# Spring Webflux functional db update does not work

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I am using spring webflux (SpringBoot 2.1.9) with reactive mongodb. Part of my build.gradle here

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

For my CRUD operation, create and delete works.  Update method does not raise an exception, but the content does not get saved in the database.  What am I doing wrong?

MyHandler.java

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> update(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(ListAndReview.class).
                flatMap( update -> {
                    return listAndReviewRepo.findById(update.id).flatMap( previous -> {
                        previous.name = update.name;
                        previous.description = update.description;
                        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(listAndReviewRepo.save(previous)));
                    });
                }
                ).
                switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
```

Comment: can you please try out to annotate your `findById` method in your `listAndReviewRepo` with `@Transactional`

Comment: Adding @Transactional did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> update(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(ListAndReview.class).
                flatMap( update -> {
                    return listAndReviewRepo.findById(update.id).flatMap( previous -> {
                        previous.name = update.name;
                        previous.description = update.description;
                        return listAndReviewRepo.save(previous)
                            .map(saved -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(saved));
                    });
                }
                ).
                switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
```

Comment: There is a right parentheses missing in 

```.map(saved -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(saved))
```But even if I add that the code does not compile.  The compile error is

`code`error: incompatible types: Mono<ServerResponse> cannot be converted to Mono<? extends Mono<ServerResponse>>
                ).switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
`code`